# Dynamic programming for basic use case Target Sum

Tags: dynamic-programming

I'm fairly new to DP, and I'm practicing to come up with a DP solution for the following problem. I've created a top-down recursive solution, but I'm having a hard time "seeing" the bottom-up DP solution.  Thanks, Clayton

Target Sum: Given an vector of integers (nums) and a target value, find the number of ways that you can add and subtract the values in nums to add up to the target.

```
class Recursive_Solution {
public:

    /* recursive solution O(2^n) time and O(n) space */
    int sumCount(vector<int>& nums, int target){
        return helper(nums, 0, 0, target);
    }
    int helper(vector<int>& nums, int i, int sum, int target){
        if (i==nums.size()) return sum==target ? 1 : 0;
        return helper(nums,i+1,sum+nums[i],target)+helper(nums,i+1,sum-nums[i],target);
    }
};

class DP_Solution {
public:
    //
    // TODO
    //
};
```